# Store the route to the "@myID" based on the key value

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a json in the following format.

```
 json_tree ={
  "Garden": {
    "Seaside": {
      "@loc": "127.0.0.1",
      "@myID": "1.3.1",
      "Shoreside": {
        "@myID": "3",
        "InfoList": {
          "Notes": {
            "@code": "0",
            "@myID": "1"
          },
          "Count": {
            "@myID": "2",
            "@val": "0"
          }
        },
        "state": "0",
        "Tid": "3",
        "Lakesshore": {
          "@myID": "4",
          "InfoList": {
            "Notes": {
              "@code": "0",
              "@oid": "1"
            },
            "Count": {
              "@myID": "2",
              "@val": "0"
            }
          },
          "state": "0",
          "Tid": "4"
        }
      },
      "state": "0",
      "Tid": "2"
    },
    "Tid": "1",
    "state": "0"
  }
}
```

My implementation:

```
def getmyID(json_tree, itemList):
    for k1, v1 in json_tree .items():
        for k,v in v1.items():
            if k == itemList:
                return '{}{}.{}'.format(json_tree['@myID'] + '.' if '@myID' in json_tree else '',
                                            v['@myID'], v['InfoList']['status']['@myID'])
```

The issue I have is that this method does not work when as it returns "None" when I want to find the route to "BackYard". Note the 'BackYard" is nested inside the "Seaside" node.

I am appending the "@myID" of the key node to the "@myID" in the respective "status" node.

```
getmyID(json_tree, "Seaside")
"Output" = "1.2.3.26" --> Currently I get this only

getmyID(json_tree, "BackYard")
"Output" = "1.2.3.75.32" --> expected output but getting "None"
```

```
The expected output of "Backyard" is created by concatenating the "@myID" of the root node which it is nested in, that is "Seaside" in this case, and concatenating it with the "@myID" of "backYard" and the "@myID" of its "status" node. 

"For a nested node, output string is formed by":

["root @myID" + "nested node "@myID" + "status node @myID"] or ["1.2.3" + "75" + "23"] for "Backyard".
```

```
"For a level node, output string is formed by":
["root @myID" + "status node @myID"] or ["1.2.3" + "26"] for "Seaside".
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: your input tree does not contain `@oid` key, you won't get either expected output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Updated the code. It was a typo on my side.

Comment: What is the `d` in `d['@myID']`?

Comment: @glibdud It is actually the json_tree, it was a typo. Apologies for it.

Comment: And is `json_Dictionary` supposed to be `json_tree`? For future reference, if you change your code at all when copying it into your post, it's a good idea to copy it back out and make sure it runs as expected before posting.

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you @glibdud I will keep it in mind for future posts. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def get_vals(d, target, path = []):
   for a, b in d.items():
      if a == target:
         yield '.'.join(filter(None, path+[b['@myID'], b["InfoList"]['status']['@myID']]))
      if isinstance(b, dict):
         yield from get_vals(b, target, path + [b.get('@myID', '')])


print(list(get_vals(json_tree, "Seaside")))
print(list(get_vals(json_tree, "BackYard")))
```

Output:

```
['1.2.3.26']
['1.2.3.75.32']
```

Edit: newest data:

```
def get_vals(d, target, paths = []):
  for a, b in d.items():
    if a == target:
      yield '.'.join(filter(None, paths+[b["@myID"], b.get("InfoList", {}).get('Notes', {}).get('@myID')]))
    if isinstance(b, dict):
      yield from get_vals(b, target, paths+[b.get('@myID')])

print(list(get_vals(json_tree, "Seaside")))
print(list(get_vals(json_tree, 'Shoreside')))
```

Output:

```
['1.3.1']
['1.3.1.3.1']
```

Comment: It works like a charm. :) Thank you so much once again!

Comment: @LauraSmith Glad to help!

Comment: I just had a quick question. May you look at the edit I made to the json_tree. For some reasons, I get an exception stating ```InfoList``` undefined. May you help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @LauraSmith That is strange, I just ran my code on your `json_tree`, and it worked fine

Comment: I am in the process to make the changes. Just give me a few minutes. Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: I made the changes to the json_tree. I have updated the ```'status'``` to ```'Notes'```.

Comment: It works well when the string is anything other than ```'Seaside"```.

Comment: @LauraSmith That is because your first input assumed that for every target key, the target value could be discovered by `b["InfoList"]['status']['@myID']`, since that was the original structure. Are you still trying to access `"InfoList"`?

Comment: Yes, I am still accessing the ```InfoList``` for the nested nodes. I agree that the strucuture changed for the parent node. Any help would be appreciated as I am unsure on how to make the code chagnes.

Comment: @LauraSmith Are you trying to find `"@myID"` after `"Shoreside"` or `InfoList`?

Comment: At the ```InfoList```, so for ```Shoreside```, I would get the ```1.3.1.3.1```. Does that answer your question, please do let me know. Thank you for your continual help.

Comment: @LauraSmith Thank you for clarifying :) What about for `"Seaside"`? Is the logic that you combine all `@myID"` key values under `"Seaside"` (or for any input key).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198266/discussion-between-laura-smith-and-ajax1234).

Comment: For a node like seaside which doesnt contain the "InfoList": {.., I would not be requesting it. May you please join the chat room?

Comment: It can return '1.3.1" for Seaside.

Comment: @LauraSmith Sorry for the delayed response, please see my recent edit.

Comment: For a nested node like ```Shoreside```, I should get ```1.3.1.3.1``` but I don't get that. Am i missing something here?

Comment: @LauraSmith Glad to help!

Answer (score -2):

EDIT - I have no problem with people down-voting my answers or even editing them, as long as they tell me why. Would love to hear back from Yvette Colomb and ChrisF.

Here is the solution I came up with using a stack-based approach. The idea is that you try to go as deep as you can in your nested structure before finding the desired key (what you called itemList). I'm sure there must be a cuter way of doing this:

```
json_tree = {
    "Gardens": {
        "Seaside": {
            "@loc": "porch",
            "@myID": "1.2.3",
            "Tid": "1",
            "InfoList": {
                "status": {
                    "@default": "0",
                    "@myID": "26"
                },
                "count": {
                    "@default": "0",
                    "@myID": "1"
                }
            },
            "BackYard": {
                "@myID": "75",
                "Tid": "2",
                "InfoList": {
                    "status": {
                        "@default": "6",
                        "@myID": "32"
                    },
                    "count": {
                        "@default": "0",
                        "@myID": "2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


def is_valid_kv_pair(key, value):
    try:
        assert isinstance(key, str)
        assert isinstance(value, dict)
        assert isinstance(value["@myID"], str)
        assert isinstance(value["Tid"], str)
        assert isinstance(value["InfoList"], dict)
        assert isinstance(value["InfoList"]["status"], dict)
        assert isinstance(value["InfoList"]["status"]["@default"], str)
        assert isinstance(value["InfoList"]["status"]["@myID"], str)
    except (AssertionError, KeyError):
        return False
    else:
        return True


def get_id(dictionary, desired_key):

    if not isinstance(dictionary, dict):
        return None

    dictionary_stack = [dictionary]
    root_stack = []
    while dictionary_stack:
        current_dictionary = dictionary_stack.pop()
        appended_root = False
        for key, value in current_dictionary.items():
            if appended_root:
                root_stack.pop()
            if is_valid_kv_pair(key, value):
                if key == desired_key:
                    rootIDs = [d["@myID"] for d in root_stack]
                    myID = value["@myID"]
                    statusID = value["InfoList"]["status"]["@myID"]
                    return ".".join(rootIDs + [myID] + [statusID])
                root_stack.append(value)
                appended_root = True
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                dictionary_stack.append(value)

    return None


ID = get_id(json_tree, "BackYard")
print(ID)
```

Comment: I think there is an issue with my code and I want to have the expected behavior as mentioned above. I am unable to figure out where the bug is in my function. And the "BackYard" is nested in the "Seaside".

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the expected output would be 1.2.75.23 for "BackYard"? Where are these numbers supposed to be coming from exactly.

Comment: I see, so the expected output for "BackYard" would be 1.2.3.75.32, not 1.2.75.23. I'll edit my answer in a bit.

Comment: Yess!! Exactly, I updated the code comments to reflect the changes. It was a typo on my end. Sorry :)

Comment: For the ```{
 "A": {
  "@myID": "1.2.3",
  "InfoList": {
   "status": {
    "@myID": "32"
   }
  },
  "B": {
   "@myID": "4.5.6",
   "InfoList": {
    "status": {
     "@myID": "64"
    }
   },
   "C": {
    "@myID": "7.8.9",
    "InfoList": {
     "status": {
      "@myID": "128"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}``` this type of json, the logic will be the same. ```getmyID(json_tree, "C") would give me "1.2.3.7.8.9.128". Does that answer your question?

Comment: Oh I see. When you mean root node, you mean not the immediate parent, but the very first node? In other words, since C is nested in B, C's ID would not be 4.5.6.7.8.9.128?